# Typescript property doesnt exist on type unknown with file uploader

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vue-component

I am trying to create an upload image vue component.  I am getting multiple errors from webstorm and Ive tried copying and pasting similar code with the same error.  I also get the error on using .click() .  The error on hover states  "Property files doesnt exist on type unknown"

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use it like this:

```ts
const fileInput = this.$refs.fileInput1 as HTMLInputElement

if (fileInput?.files && fileInput.files[0]){
  formData.append('image_main', fileInput.files[0])
}
```